# How to force composer to automatically ignore warrning?

Tags: automation, composer-php

I'm making shell script which will install symfony 4 on ubuntu automatically. Since I'm using apache I have to execute:

```
composer require symfony/apache-pack
```

However, that command asks me to confirm:

```
composer require symfony/apache-pack

The recipe for this package comes from the "contrib" repository, which is open to community contributions.
    Review the recipe at https://github.com/symfony/recipes-contrib/tree/master/symfony/apache-pack/1.0

Do you want to execute this recipe?
    [y] Yes
    [n] No
    [a] Yes for all packages, only for the current installation session
    [p] Yes permanently, never ask again for this project
    (defaults to n): y
```

And I can't use `--no-interaction` options since default value is "n". How can I change this command not to ask me to confirm this action, but to automatically installs this apache pack?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This does not answer the question per se, but you can get rid of your specific warning per project if you add the following to your `composer.json`:

```
"extra": {
    "symfony": {
        "allow-contrib": true
    }
}
```

or, even better, you can use Composer itself to set the flag before installing `symfony/apache-pack`:

```
composer config extra.symfony.allow-contrib true
```

This will make possible for Flex to install contrib recipes (i.e. recipes provided by the community) automatically, without asking for permission.

Comment: This would solve the problem if I could set that parameter trough the console command. Is that possible?

Comment: Yep, that works. Thanks! Maybe not the way as I imagined it would, but definitely solves my problem.

Comment: I'm glad it helped!